# Angular 6 cannot get the new value typed inside an input displaying data from ngFor loop data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am getting data and display it inside an input of a reactive form:

```
<div *ngFor="let users of getUsersArray; let i = index;">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput color="warn" 
        [value]="users.role_type" 
        formControlName="edit_role_type" placeholder="Role Type">
    </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
</div>
```

This form control is created inside a reactive form:

```
'edit_role_type': new FormControl({value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
```

I have an update button, so if a user wants to update the field with new data:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" 
    (click)="updateUser(users)" [disabled]="formGroup4.valid">
    <mat-icon>update</mat-icon> Update Data
</button>
```

If I console the value of `users` on update button click, I can see the data generated from the `*ngFor`.

If I changed the value and console it, I only see the old values and the new typed one isn't displayed.

Here is the update button script:

```
updateUser(users){
    console.log(users)
    let email = this.formGroup4.controls['edit_user_email'].value;
    if(this.formGroup4.get('edit_user_password').hasError('minLength'))
    {
         //Password error
    }
   else if(email!='' && !email.endsWith('@test.org'))
   {
        //return email error
   }
   else
  {
      this.auth.updateUserData(users).subscribe(
        (data)=>{

        },
        (error)=>{
          console.log(error)
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you also post the code you use to change the user? if you just change it by reference, this will not work which is why I need to see the code (the one you trigger on button click, the "updateUser" method)

Comment: Okay give me 2 minutes.

Comment: @pascalpuetz you can check the button script now.

Comment: Where do you change the user in getUsersArray? There is no code where you reflect the change back to the array. I expected that to happen in updateUser but it seems you're just calling a service there.

Comment: `getUsersArray` is a simple array that we iterate over to display data sent from server using `*ngFor`

Comment: Yep, and that array needs to be changed if you change the user. Usually you'd do that by using a formArray containing the formControls and don't mix them. That's why I was asking where you reflect the changes in your array when a user changes (you're binding to the array via [value]="users.role_type")

Comment: how to use form arrays without mixing them

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Answer (score 3):

You should not bind `[value]="users.role_type"` to the input when using reactive forms. Use just `formControlName` and set the value when creating the `FormControl`.

In your `formGroup` you should have a `FormArray` and create edit_role_type `FormControl` for each user in your array.

When using reactive forms the model used to prefill the data is not two way bound. Users array will not be changed when input value changes. Instead in your update click handler you should get the data from form: `this.formGroup.value` and update your users based on the form data.

Or you can drop reactive forms and use model driven forms and use two way binding through `[(ngModel)]`.